# Scaling Bordered and Non-Bordered Flash Graphics Equally

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I have a SWF file containing two symbols which have are "exported for ActionScript". These are both simple squares whose fill is equal in size, but one has a border and the other does not.

> [image]

I would like to display these graphics side-by-side in my Flash application, and I would like them both to be scaled (enlarged) to the same dimensions. I've written some fairly simple code to load these symbols from the SWF and display them (see below), but the bordered element is not sized as expected:

> [image]

The border causes the graphic to be reduced in size by more than the border enlarges it.

---

I used the following code to perform the above test.

```
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<s:Application
    xmlns:fx='http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009'
    xmlns:s='library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark'
    xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx"
    initialize='init(drawArea)'
>
<mx:UIComponent id='drawArea' left='0' top='0' width='250' height='250'></mx:UIComponent>
<fx:Script><![CDATA[
import mx.controls.SWFLoader;

static function init(drawArea:UIComponent):void {
    var loader:SWFLoader = new SWFLoader();
    loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onSwfLoaded);
    loader.load('./borderings.swf');

    function onSwfLoaded(e:Event):void {
        var getDefinition:Function = e.target.loaderContext.applicationDomain.getDefinition;

        var Bordered:Class = getDefinition('bordered');
        var bordered:MovieClip = new Bordered;

        bordered.x = 100;
        bordered.y = 100;
        bordered.width = 100;
        bordered.height = 100;

        var borderedContents:DisplayObject = bordered.getChildAt(0);
        assert(bordered.numChildren === 1);

        assert(borderedContents.x == 0);
        assert(borderedContents.y == 0);
        assert(borderedContents.width == 14.1);
        assert(borderedContents.height == 14.1);

        drawArea.addChild(bordered);


        var Borderless:Class = getDefinition('borderless');
        var borderless:MovieClip = new Borderless;

        borderless.x = 250;
        borderless.y = 100;
        borderless.width = 100;
        borderless.height = 100;

        var borderlessContents:DisplayObject = borderless.getChildAt(0);
        assert(borderless.numChildren === 1);

        assert(borderlessContents.x == 0);
        assert(borderlessContents.y == 0);
        assert(borderlessContents.width == 13.1);
        assert(borderlessContents.height == 13.1);

        drawArea.addChild(borderless);

        drawArea.graphics.lineStyle(1.0, 0xFF0000, 1.0);
        drawArea.graphics.moveTo(25, 50);
        drawArea.graphics.lineTo(325, 50);
        drawArea.graphics.moveTo(25, 150);
        drawArea.graphics.lineTo(325, 150);
    }
}

static function assert(pass:Boolean, msg:String=null):void {
    if (!pass) throw new Error(msg || 'assertion failed');
}
]]></fx:Script>
</s:Application>
```

The complete IntelliJ test project may be found [in this git repository on BitBucket](https://bitbucket.org/jeremybanks/flash-graphics-testing).

---

The Flash editor claims that the symbols both have the same dimensions: 13.10px by 13.10px, although visually this appears to be excluding the outer half of the border:

> [image]

However, when I inspect instances of these graphics using ActionScript it reports that the the bordered graphic is larger, at 14.10px by 14.10px.

---

Why is the sizing of these graphics affected by the border in this odd way? How can I cause the bordered and unbordered versions of this graphic to be scaled to the same dimensions?

Comment: Are you sure both boxes have their registration point in the same place? That could explain the alignment error.

Comment: @frankhermes That was helpful, thanks. I had created the borderless symbol by duplicating the bordered symbol and removing the border, so the registration point was duplicated and is in the same position relative to the fill in both symbols. However, this point was above and to the left of the graphics themselves, so the distance between the point and the graphic were different in the two cases.

Comment: I went in and re-created those graphics to use a registration point in the centre, which sort-of fixed their alignment, except now it's caused the graphics to appear at slightly different sizes (which I don't think was the case before), rather than slightly different positions. I'll update the question.

Comment: I've found that setting setting `bordered.scaleX = borderless.scaleX;` and such, instead of setting `bordered.width` directly, gives me something that looks much better. However, this doesn't help me in the case that I don't have a borderless graphic for reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the scaling issue you might take a look at the `getRect()` method of `DisplayObject`.

From [AS3 Reference for `getRect()`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/DisplayObject.html#getRect%28%29):

> Returns a rectangle that defines the boundary of the display object, based on the coordinate system defined by the `targetCoordinateSpace` parameter, excluding any strokes on shapes. The values that the `getRect()` method returns are the same or smaller than those returned by the `getBounds()` method.

For the example above, this can be used to directly figure out the scale factors required to set an element to specific dimensions while ignoring the strokes, instead of using setting the scale through the `width` and `height` properties. A function like this would work:

```
static function setDimensionsExcludingStrokes(
    subject:DisplayObject, width:int=-1, height:int=-1
):void {
    var innerDimensions:Rectangle = subject.getRect(subject);

    if (width >= 0) {
        subject.scaleX = width / innerDimensions.width;
    }

    if (height >= 0) {
        subject.scaleY = height / innerDimensions.height;
    }
}
```

Instead of setting `bordered.width = 100` and `bordered.height = 100`, we would call:

```
setDimensionsExcludingStrokes(bordered, 100, 100);
```

This results in the squares being nicely-aligned at the same target size:

> [image]

Comment: Thanks for the help; this allowed me to solve my issue. I've added some code to your answer to show how this could be applied to the specific problem stated above.